# Spring Annotation @CreatedBy and @CreatedByDate is not working but @LastModifiedBy and @LastModified date is working

Tags: spring, spring-boot, spring-annotations

I am trying to create a document class where I am adding fields
creationTime,LastmodificationTime, createdBy and  LastModifiedBy by using respective annotations.
What I am seeing is that
class variables with annotations
@CreatedBy and @CreatedDate are getting populated as null but the ones with @LastModifiedBy and @LastModifiedDate are.

Here's the code for the actual class

```
import com.abcd.ops.cp.bo.BaseDBEntity;
import lombok.*;
import org.springframework.data.annotation.Id;
import org.springframework.data.mongodb.core.mapping.Document;

import java.util.Collection;
import java.util.Set;

@Document
@Getter
@Setter
@NoArgsConstructor
//@AllArgsConstructor
@Builder
public class RoleMapping extends BaseDBEntity {

    @Id
    private String roleName;

    private Set<RBACEntity> entities;

    private String description;

    private RoleType roleType = RoleType.SYSTEM_DEFINED;

    @Builder
    public RoleMapping(String roleName, Set<RBACEntity> entities, String description, RoleType roleType) {
        super(roleName);
        this.roleName = roleName;
        this.entities = entities;
        this.description = description;
        this.roleType = roleType;
    }
}
```

Here's the BaseDBEntity.java

```
package com.abcd.ops.cp.bo;

import lombok.*;
import org.springframework.data.annotation.*;

import java.util.Date;

@Getter
@Setter
@NoArgsConstructor
public abstract class BaseDBEntity {

    @CreatedBy
    private String createdBy;

    @CreatedDate
    private Date creationDate;

    @LastModifiedDate
    private Date lastModifiedDate;

    @LastModifiedBy
    private String lastModifiedBy;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

`@CreatedDate` will not be populated, if entity already have ID in the DB. So underlying framework understands, that it was created before and therefore Created Date is not needed to be updated.
Unlike `@CreatedDate`, `@LastModifiedDate` is always being populated, regardless if object was already persisted or not.

Answer (score 0):

you need to add some annotations:

```
    package com.abcd.ops.cp.bo;
    
    import lombok.*;
    import org.springframework.data.annotation.*;
    
    import java.util.Date;
    
    @Getter
    @Setter
    @NoArgsConstructor
    @MappedSuperclass
    @EntityListeners(AuditingEntityListener.class)
    public abstract class BaseDBEntity {
    
        @CreatedBy
        private String createdBy;
    
        @CreatedDate
        private Date creationDate;
    
        @LastModifiedDate
        private Date lastModifiedDate;
    
        @LastModifiedBy
        private String lastModifiedBy;
    }
```

And also you need a config class like:

```
    @Configuration
    @EnableJpaAuditing(auditorAwareRef = "auditorProvider")
    class JpaAuditingConfig {
    
        @Bean
        foo auditorProvider(): AuditorAware<String> {
            return AuditorAware { Optional.of(SecurityContextHolder.getContext().authentication.name) }
        }

    }
```